# Locked out of sandbox login, can I change it manually from prod?

Tags: login

A fellow developer who I just got on this project informed me two days ago that he was unable to log in to the sandbox, and the password reset sent to my email. So, today, I tried to reset it. I tried to answer the security question -- the same it's been for almost a year -- and it wouldn't take. It ended up locking me out for 24 hours, but even then, the security question won't work because I was unable to answer it today (even though it hasn't changed...). What are my options? I am able to log in to production with a different login -- the only admin login -- but when I click "Login" by the sandbox, the creds don't work because they're different from the sandbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to submit a case (in production) to have them unlock/reset your password in the sandbox. Your only other alternative would be to refresh the sandbox, which I presume you don't want to do, since you would lose all modifications you've made since the last refresh.